# Spring Cloud Security with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to implement a spring-boot-web application, secured using spring-cloud-security with an external on-premise authentication server (WSO2 Identity Server). We're using OAuth2 OpenID Connect (JWT tokens).

My application will redirect to the WSO2 server just fine for the /oauth2/authorize request, but is failing when it tries to convert the authorization_code into an access_token. spring-boot reports a 401 authentication error.

I believe this is because the oauth2/token endpoint requires basic authentication.

Can someone guide me how to make the /oauth2/token request use basic authentication headers with spring-cloud-security?

Here's my application.yml

```
spring:
  oauth2:
    sso:
      home:
        secure: false
        path: /,/**/*.html
    client:
      accessTokenUri: https://URI:9443/oauth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://URI:9443/oauth2/authorize
      clientId: id
      clientSecret: secret
      scope: openid
      clientAuthenticationScheme: header
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://URI:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

Here is my simple application.java

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.sso.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.sso.OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SpringOauth2WithWso2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringOauth2WithWso2Application.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
          public void match(RequestMatchers matchers) {
            matchers.anyRequest();
          }

          @Override
          public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
          }



        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                            .getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: It turns out the error was due to wso2 identity server using self-signed certificates. We diagnosed it by adding -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to the spring-boot startup command.  We resolved this issue by adding the WSO2 server's public certificate to the java truststore of the spring-boot application.  Problem solved.

Comment: It would be worth posting a full answer else this post will end up wasting people's time if they wish to use it to help them integrate Spring Cloud Security (particularly Spring Security OAuth2) with WSO2 IS. For example, this issue/thread certainly has relevance if you wish to use Spring Security OAuth2 with WSO2 IS: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/63 (note the need to change from bearer to Bearer when trying to access the users identity, the final step in the chain). Could also just change the title (Spring Cloud Security with WSO2 IS) to something less generic.

Answer (score 0):

Although the need to add the WSO2 IS certificate to the Java Certificate Store has been mentioned as a solution, in case it helps anyone the steps required to do so, as well as set up mitmproxy so you can inspect the traffic has been documented here by means of a template project: https://github.com/nicodewet/template-spring-boot-oauth2-wso2-is